# Show different Google Map markers for different post_meta values

Tags: loop, google-maps

A lot of websites use it but suprisingly nobody tell us how to do it (right way).

I have few ideas but Im not sure if this was the most efficient way - Im not very good with loops (under a year of experience in programming).

Raw example:

Have lots of `if` statements in `foreach` or `while` loop.

```
// All this inside loop - I've already got while loop for my multiple markers
global $post;
$veggie_type = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'veggie_type', true);

if($veggie_type == 'carrot') {

     icon = marker_url_1;

}
else if($veggie_type == 'beet') {

     icon = marker_url_2;

}
//etc like 10 if statements
```

Could anyone give me an advice or example?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Do you just want to make your 10 if statements more compact?

Comment: @MSTannu Im asking if there's a better way to add different markers to different values (doesn't matter if different meta, post type etc)? If there is none, I would take the advice how to make this more compact.

Comment: How are the valid types of veggies defined?

Comment: @Milo It doesn't show in my example but the values I have are taxonomies (slugs) that I need to assign different map markers to. ..or Im not fully understanding what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta seems like a fine place for storing this data.

To make it more compact:

```
$markers = array(
    'carrot' => 'marker_url_1',
    'beet'   => 'marker_url_2',
);

$icon = isset( $markers[ $veggie_type ] ) ? $markers[ $veggie_type ] : $markers[0];
```

Or if you are sure you have markers for each type and you can rename the marker files, go with

```
$icon = 'marker_' . $veggie_type . '.png';// png format is better for small images
```